# How to use UTC time on client side?

Tags: javascript

My script works so far that the right things are shown on the website, AS long AS I am in my time zone. As soon as I change the time zone the browser shows content in the client time. Now its is crucial that things on the website are shown in my time zone time. Why is then script not working correctly?

```
var imgElement = document.createElement("img");

var time = new Date((new Date()).toLocaleString("en-US", {timeZone: "America/Regina"})).getHours();


 if (time >= 0 && time <= 4) {
```

Comment: It's not clear at all what you're asking or even what the problem is, if any.

Comment: If you want the UTC hour, use [Date.prototype.getUTCHours()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getUTCHours)... `const time = new Date().getUTCHours()`

Comment: Date objects represent time by the number of milliseconds since 1 Jan 1970 0:00:00UTC - so, no need to get fancy with timezones

Comment: @Phil
I run a script that gets the time, checks for the hour and shows website content that is related to the hour. Problem is: No matter how I get the time .getHour() or getUTCHour() on the client side the content is shown in the client time, not in the time here. But since these are radioshows it is crucial that lets say someone opens the website at 3 am in the morning in his timezone and in my time sone its lets say 10 am the user need to see the content from 10 am because the shows are in my time zone. 
I hope that makes it more clear

Comment: @JaromandaX unfortunately its not that simple.

Comment: So you're talking about formatting the dates in a particular timezone? What does the code in your question have to do with that?

Comment: @Phil Well I am a beginner in Javascript and my idea was to get the time, check for the hour and display the show on the website which is currently on. As you can imagine the show runs in  my time zone/ But if a user goes on the website it would show him a different show because the browser uses the users time zone. I dont know how to fix that. The browser needs to use the time information that I provide...

Comment: Ok, so question for you... why do you need the client to send any time information at all? Can you not use the current time at the server to determine what to return? If you do need to send time data over the network, serialise them to [ISO 8601 UTC format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601). Then you can parse them and display them any way you like

Comment: `its not that simple` - OK, then just do `const time = +new Date().toLocaleString("en-CA", {timeZone: "America/Regina", hour:"numeric", hour12: false});` and you'll get the hours in Regina in 24 hour format, i.e. 0-23

Comment: @JaromandaX I think that he needs the time to be in his timeZone...
Not meant formating, but rather the value. He complains that the user would see what show is playing which will not be correct because he is using the time to determine what show is playing.
e.g. playing show 1 between 0-4 in his timezone
when i run the site on my locale in germany my time will be 8 which will be incorrect because that does not corespond with his show and on his locale the time is 2

Comment: @jakubpodhaisky - OP's question is one thing, his comments are another - and interestingly, your answer produces the SAME result as my suggestion, but you had to use a library to do so, one that is no longer maintaned! - so, not sure why you felt the need to make a comment suggesting I got it wrong, since you did EXACTLY the same thing

Comment: @JaromandaX my apologies. I produced the wrong result with you seggestion. I tried it today again and yes it works. When I tried it first I changed the time on my computer and it didn't show the desired result. My mistake was: I changed the time. Not the timezone. I didn't mean to offend. I was frustrated.after two days of cracking my head over it.

Answer (score -1):

```js
var timeInMyTimeZone = moment.tz("America/Regina");

var hourInMyTimeZone = timeInMyTimeZone.hour();

if (hourInMyTimeZone >= 0 && hourInMyTimeZone <= 4) {
  // Your code to show specific content
  console.log("Show content for 0-4 AM in America/Regina");
} else {
  // Handle other time periods
  console.log("Show content for other times.");
}
// Show time in my timezone
console.log(timeInMyTimeZone);
// Show hour in my timezone
console.log(hourInMyTimeZone)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.34/moment-timezone-with-data.min.js"></script>
```

You can use momentTimezone to achieve the behaviour you need

please note that you need to change the timezone you want as a parameter to .tz()
see the documentation [here](https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/)

Comment: That works. I was looking into the moment.tz as well. Thanks. Yes that makes total sense. Learnt something. Thank you.